# How can I set flash notices for each situations from Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My User model:

```
validates :password, :presence => { allow_blank: false, notice: "password error" }
validates :username, :presence => { allow_blank: false, notice: "username error" }
```

User Controller:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        logger.info "saved"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "This field is empty"
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

How can I do that instead "This field is empty" to take text from model for each situation.

For ex: if error in username field, show "username error", for password -> "password error" etc. So, how can I take these texts from model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user.errors` contains the validation errors.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    logger.info "saved"
  else
    flash[:notice] = @user.errors.to_a.to_sentence
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes! It works! But it prints: "Password password error" instead of "password error". How can I remove the first part of error?

Comment: The field name is automatically appended, so your message in the model must not include it.